# Does anyone know what frame my bike is?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

Does anyone know what frame my bike is?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Without any sharp close ups of the decals, my guess is that it's a bmx frame.

Comment: Please add clear close ups of the four stickers please - Right-chainstay, lower-right downtube, upper-left downtube, and forward-right toptube.

Comment: @michel Please clarify, have you mirrored these photos or is the chainring really on the left-hand side of the bike?

Comment: I would say Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what the bike is, probably doesn't matter in the long term.  Most bikes draw from a set of standards, so many parts are interchangeable.

The most unusual thing about your bike is that the entire drive system is on the left-hand side of the frame, unlike the vast bulk of bikes that have the chain on the right-hand side.

This implies it is intended as a stunt/trick bike, where the rider can "grind" on rails the opposite way to normal.  Of course this makes conventional grinding impossible.

Your bike probably had grinding pegs on both sides of each axle originally, and if it has been stunted, there are likely gouges under the bottom bracket.

I also observe someone has removed the front brake entirely, and there appears to be no provision for a rear brake at all.   I cannot see evidence of a detangler or a Potts mod, so its unlikely to be road-safe.  If you're going to ride this bike, fit working brakes please.

Further info: [Do Left handed bikes feel different to ride?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56465/do-left-handed-bikes-feel-different-to-ride)